# Can't grant permission to IIS_IUSRS on windows container

Tags: windows, containers, windows-server-container

I'm building a image, which was made by `microsoft/aspnet` and builder OS:

```
C:\> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
```

, I got error after running `RUN icacls 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'`

> Invalid parameter "'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'"
>   The command 'cmd /S /C icacls 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'' returned a non-zero code: 87

---

But under the base image which was made by `microsoft/aspnet` and builder OS

```
PS C:\> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
```

Was totally OK, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your codes are okay but a very lil mistake
Try this
icacls '\inetpub\wwwroot\' /grant "IIS_IUSRS":f
Hope your problem will solve.

Comment: It worked!! thanks so much!  and it's weird, it also worked with `RUN icacls '\inetpub\wwwroot\' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'` (without drive letter)

Comment: If using **windowsservercore-ltsc2019**, it only worked by `RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ /grant "IIS_IUSRS":f`